# SQL query using a pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

[image: full screenshots of tables here]

I’m trying to create a view to show reservations from our DotNetNuke Reservations module.
 We have created some custom fields on the module which don’t show by default.
 e.g. this table dbo.Reservations_CustomFieldDefinition has some fields we want to show (ID = 6 is one of them because that shows National Insurance numbers, and if ID is 7 that's special requests)

update - here's some sample data (with simplified tables):
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39be49/5

and a desired outcome:

| ReservationName | CategoryName | NI_Number | Requirements |

| Adam            | Amsterdam    | AA1       | an apple  |

| Brian           | Barnsley     | BB2       | a banana |

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of your first join (`ON R.ReservationID = C.ReservationID;`), this is causing SQL to think that the bit you have added is a statement in its own right. Just remove the semicolon and you should no longer receive the syntax error.

Comment: thanks, I think the 2 lines are messed up completely (now it doesn't recognise CategoryID).

The table Reservations_Reservation contains pretty much all fields (CategoryID and CustomFieldDefinitionID) Maybe I need another PIVOT in there? and try to reference the Name field in CategoryID in the same way as Ni_No and Special_Request.

Comment: The only fields you have in the CTE `CustomFields`, are `ReservationID, NI_No, Special_Request`. You need to select `CategoryID` in your CTE in order to use it in a JOIN later on

Comment: Thanks, 
I've added 'CategoryID' to the query, but if I add the table called 'Reservations_Category' - I get 10x entries than there should be (so I need to use some kind of JOIN, but I'm not sure how or where.

E.g.
`code
SELECT ReservationID, CustomFieldDefinitionID, Value, CategoryID
  FROM dbo.Reservations_CustomFieldValue, Reservations_Category"
`code`
  'CategoryID' also Appears in this table: 'Reservations_Reservation', but if I use that table instead,  I get an error saying:    Ambiguous column name 'ReservedID'

Comment: The most likely reason you will be getting 10x the number of entries is because CategoryID is not unique with each ReservationID, which means that if you only want a single CategoryID per ReservationID you need to provide some logic on how to choose a categoryID. I think you are going to need to post some example data, and expected output.

Comment: While producing a sqlfiddle is helpful, you need to ensure that the data "makes sense". I found that no RESID in CFVALUE matched RESID in RESERVATIONS and that CF_ID 6 or 7 didn't work in the pivot becuse neither were used in the data. amended sqlfiddle which works, but unsure that the data is now viable: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4aff39/2

Comment: thanks, I suppose that its not possible then using that join I used 'ON R.ResID = C.ResID;' to query those fields. (think we're going to get rid of some custom fields to simplify the process). Thanks for all the comments.